# Vector calculus notation, maybe?

Tags: vectors, notation, differentiation

I just got a new book on turbomachinery that uses some notation I'm not familiar with.

$$ \nabla \lor \vec{W} = -2\vec{\Omega} $$

The del-(something)-vector format makes me think its vector calculus. From context (rotating equipment), maybe its vector calculus in a cylindrical coordinate system? Or the list of symbols says the V-like symbol is "vector product", so is this just non-standard notation for curl?

For context, W is the relative velocity between the rotating equipment and the fluid, and omega is the angular speed (this bit is also confusing since speed is not a vector, but this equation identifies it as one).

What does $\nabla \lor \text{vector}$ mean?

Comment: I think it is a rotational, but you should provide more context: what is $W$? What is $\Omega$?

Comment: $\vec{\nabla} \lor \vec{W}$, $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{W}$, $\text{curl } \vec{W}$ all mean the same thing.

Comment: Research Clifford algebra. It extends vector calculus to multi-dimensions.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch, while that is comment length, it seems to answer the whole questiion. So if you'd like to make it an answer, I'd accept. Thanks!

Comment: @BillN I think you mean exterior algebra (unless we have a particular quadratic form here), but it seems more likely that this is simply another notation for the cross-product.

Comment: @levitopher Yeah, Clifford is a particular exterior algebra.  Related to the question, I have actually never seen the upside-down wedge used anywhere. Who uses that notation? exterior algebra uses $\wedge$.

Comment: @BillN I found it in this book: https://www.amazon.com/Design-Analysis-Centrifugal-Compressors-Wiley-ASME/dp/1119424097/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=centrifugal+compressor&qid=1555693351&rnid=2941120011&s=books&sr=1-1#reader_1119424097

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several notations in use for
the [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)) of a vector field $\vec{W}$:

- $\vec{\nabla} \lor \vec{W}$
- $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{W}$
- $\text{curl } \vec{W}$

And they all mean the same thing.